# Numbers that are equal to the concatenation of the positions of its primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Given a natural number $N\in\mathbb N$, we can construct another number as follows: Let $p_1\leq p_2\leq\ldots\leq p_n$ the prime factorisation of $N$, where duplicates can occur. Let $\pi$ be the prime-counting function and write $a\|b$ for the concatenation of digits in base 10, then let $\psi(N)=\pi(p_1)\|\pi(p_2)\|\cdots\|\pi(p_n)$.

I am interested in numbers $N$ such that $N=\psi(N)$. Examples are $2\cdot 7=14=1\|4=\pi(2)\|\pi(7)$ and $3\cdot709=2127=2\|127=\pi(3)\|\pi(709)$. I searched for numbers up to $10^6$, but couldn't find any more (unfortunately, my programming skills aren't good enough to search much further).

Interesting questions that I would like to know the answer to include

- Can you explicitely find any more such numbers?
- How many of these numbers are there?
- Can you construct bounds on the number of primes in the factorisation of $N$ or the size of $N$ depending on the number of primes in its factorisation?
- Can every prime occur as a factor in such a number?
- Feel free to point out any other interesting properties you find.

It might be the case that this has a really easy answer and I'm just stupid, but the only thing I managed to prove is that there are no other numbers other than the two above with $\psi(N)=N$ and $N$ has two prime factors, by using the inequalities $a\|b\leq (10a+1)b$ and $\pi(p)\leq\frac{1.3p}{\log p}$, thus finding bounds on $p_2$ in terms of $p_1$ and checking all remaining possibilities.

I am looking forward to all of your ideas and observations.

Comment: (+1) I currently run a search upto $10^7$

Comment: No more solutions in the range $[2,10^7]$

Comment: Number $1232495490=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot41083183$ is an example.  A similar problem where duplicates are not included in concatenations (we have concatenations of distinct primes), is [A329026](https://oeis.org/A329026) = $12, 14, 2127, 1232495490, ?,\dots$ where only four examples are known.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Somehow I didn't find that sequence when searching the OEIS.

Comment: Incredible that this is in OEIS

Comment: I've checked $N=n\cdot p$ for $n\lt 10^3$, $\pi (p)\lt 10^{10}$ and only $(n,p)$ pairs that work are $$(2,7), (3,709), (30,41083183),$$ if my calculations are correct. That is, I've iterated $n\in (0,10^3], a\in[0,10)$ assuming $\pi(p)=10^a+b$, where we can for a given $a$ estimate bounds for $b$ by numerically solving $$n \cdot P(10^a + b) - (\psi({n})\cdot10^{a + 1} + 10^a+b) = 0$$ for $b$, where $P(n)$ is an estimation for $n$-th prime, e.g.  $n(\ln n+\ln \ln n)>$ $P(n)$ $> n(\ln n+\ln \ln n-1)$. I've used binary search to get $b$ (from estimated bounds) that minimizes $|N-\psi({N})|$.

Comment: Rule out any $m$ digit number that has more than $m$ prime factors, or that isn't all 1,2,3,4 ...

Comment: *Continuing my previous comment, I've extended my limit for $\pi(p)$ and am trying to cover all cases.* Let $p$ be the largest prime factor of example $N\in\{14,2127,1232495490,\dots\}$. The ratios $\frac{N}{p}$ for these examples are $\{2,3,30,\dots\}$, respectively. For the next example $N$, it holds that the ratio is $\frac{N}{p}\gt 1000$; *or otherwise, there are only 655 remaining potential solutions with a smaller ratio (one of remaining 87 potential ratios) that I haven't yet ruled out, as computing $k$-th prime $p_k$ for large $k$ is very slow in WA Mathematica.*